# Order of Concatenation for Transform in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, concatenation, swift-playground

While using playground I discovered somewhat of an unexpected scenario

I was translating a `square(w: 100, h: 100)` from `(0,0)` to `(150, 150)` and rotating it .pi. I was using concatenation to translate and rotate the square at the same time, so this came as a surprise but when I switched what order I was calling the translation and rotation, the square would move different ways

When I rotated the square before I translated it, the square would move from`(0,0)` to `(150, 150)`, as predicted

However, when I translated before I rotated the square, the square would move from `(0,0)` and rotate up and left off the screen, which to me doesn't logically make sense, can someone try and explain this to me?

[image: Code from the Playground]

[image: Two Lines of Code Changed]

Comment: When applying affine transformations the order of operations matters. I don’t remember enough from classess to provide a complete answer, and couldn’t find an article with iOS examples, but this one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/why-transformation-order-is-significant - explains the general concepts and could help clear some things conceptually for you.

Comment: Hrmm, that makes sense, however, when I ran the code, it did the exact opposite of what that site explains. However I may just be misunderstanding something key here, thanks!

Comment: Different graphics systems use different coordinate systems. I haven't studied the Windows graphic system particularly, but if you're seeing exactly the opposite behavior, then it's likely either a left-hand/right-hand rotational difference, or a lower-left vs upper-left origin difference. My suggestion (having gone through re-learning all this myself not too long ago), is to go back to the underlying linear algebra: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab (videos 1-5 are enough for CGGraphics)

Comment: If you want your transformations to be simpler to reason about, the key is put the center of the object at the origin (rather than a corner being at the origin). When you do that, all the transformations tend to work the way you probably meant them to.

Comment: Don't show pictures of code. Show code.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of matrix algebra, the order in which transforms are applied in `concatenating` (aka `CGAffineTransformConcat`) is the *opposite* of the order in which you would apply them one by one to get the same effect.

Comment: Might help you to read my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_transform