# CGAffineTransform concatenation: appropriate order of transformations

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I know that whenever we want to apply a series of transform at once to a point, we have to specify the sequence in the opposite direction to what we want to perceive. If I want to translate(**T**) and then rotate(**R**) a point **x** we  need to end with a concatenation matrix **RT**, then every point is transformed as **(RT)x**.

[Apple Transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html) documentation shows that CGAffineTransform work as a transpose version of the above expression. i.e instead of transform a points as **Ax** for **A** being any transform matrix they do it as **xB** for **B** being the transpose of **A**.

Also [CGAffineTransform.concatenating(T2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html) documentation state that it stack transforms to the right, ending in an transform matrix of the form as **T1 * T2**.

Now what are my concerns? If want a series of transformation that `translate`(**T**) and then `rotate`(**R**), I can call `T.concatenating(R)` which result in a transform **TR**, then the points are transformed as **xTR**, it seem that the order must be respected, but actually I'm getting the wrong result(*at least that's what i think*), I expect the image A but getting B,

[image]

It seem that they are transforming points as **TRx**, but this contradict the documentation and also not match the result when you apply the transform **TR** to a point as [CGPoint.applying(TR)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpoint/1454251-applying) which also is consistent with the order **xTR**.

why's that? there's something that I'm missing about how transforms works in iOS?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see what the question is here, because you've already answered it. Basically, the order you must use when calling `concatenating` is the opposite of the order you would use when chaining transformations. Thus for example:

```
v2.transform = 
     CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45 * .pi/180).translatedBy(x: 100, y: 0)
```

In this screen shot, `v2` is the green view, and started out where the purple view is:

[image]

If you wanted to do that with `concatenating`, you'd say:

```
let r = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45 * .pi/180)
let t = CGAffineTransform(translationX:100, y:0)
v2.transform = t.concatenating(r) // not r.concatenating(t)
```

Comment: (Discussion and examples come straight from my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_transform)

Comment: Just to be sure, in the screenshot,  the rectangle in green is obtained by first a rotation then a translation?

Comment: i think it's wrong: v2.transform = t.concatenating(r),   this means you translate first then rotate.

Comment: @John The purpose of my answer is to set you straight about that. See also my https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588987/341994

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, your confusion lies not with order of operations, but with the rotate transformation. Rotation does not take place about the object's center, but about the origin of the frame, which remains fixed in place. When you rotate an object not centered at the frame's origin, it pivots around like the end of the hand of a clock. To achieve image A, you must

1. Translate your object so that the point you wish to rotate it about (presumably its center) lies at the origin.
2. Rotate the object.
3. Translate it to the desired position.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the transform is already from the object center and the steps you mentioned were made, the problem is that I want translate->then->rotate, so i get image A, but actually I'm getting image B, which is the result of rotate->then->translate. T.concatenating(R) is supposed to produce a matrix TR which transform points as as in image A, but the result is B.