# CGAffineTransform operations inconsistency in order applied

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to understand the results of chaining two transformations using CGAffineTransform in iOS. Based on Apple's documentation, combining translation and scaling is working as expected, but combining translation and rotation is not.

I think the question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910034/cgaffinetransform-concatenation-appropriate-order-of-transformations) was onto the same observation, but I am combining translation with scaling to show the inconsistent behavior. Or is there some consistent way to understand what order the transformations will take place using these methods?

Apple's [CGAffineTransform documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) shows transforming a point, represented by a row vector `[x y 1]`, by multiplying on the right by a matrix. To use the notation used in the CGAffineTransform header file, this matrix is `[a b c d tx ty]` (because the last column is always the transpose of `[0 0 1]`). Because the matrix is on the right of the row vector, if we have two CGAffineTransform matrices `A` and `B`, the product `AB` applied to a point will first apply the transformation `A` and then apply the operation `B` (which is opposite of what typical linear algebra books do).

Using a translation transform `t`, a scaling transformation `s`, and a rotation transform `r`, I have examined the resulting transforms and their effects on views for the following:

```
 s.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 0) // translates first, then scales
 s.concatenating(t) // scales first, then translates
 t.rotated(by: 45 * .pi/180) // translates first, then rotates
 t.concatenating(r) // rotates first, then translates
```

I understand that `concatenating` will perform in the reverse order as you see when performing an operation such as `translatedBy`. But, per [concatenating: documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455996-concatenating), `A.concatenatig(B)` should give the transformation `AB`, which as noted above performs transformation `A` followed by `B`. That indeed happens on `s.concatenating(t)`, but not `t.concatenating(r)`. Based on the example in [Matt's iOS book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_transform), here is some code to setup.

```
 let v1 = UIView(frame:CGRect(20, 111, 132, 194))
 v1.backgroundColor = .red
 view.addSubview(v1)

 let v2 = UIView(frame:v1.bounds)
 v2.backgroundColor = .green
 v1.addSubview(v2)

 let v3 = UIView(frame: v1.bounds)
 v3.backgroundColor = .blue
 v1.addSubview(v3)

 let t = CGAffineTransform(translationX:100, y:0)
 let r = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45 * .pi/180)
 let s = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
```

Then you can add this code to see that translating and scaling works as expected:

```
 // translates first, then scales
 v2.transform = s.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 0)
 // scales first, then translates
 v3.transform = s.concatenating(t)
```

[Green v2 translates 100 to the right and then is scaled by .1, where blue v3 is scaled by .1 and then translated 100 to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xNNC.png)

However, the behavior for translating and rotating is different:

```
 // translates first, then rotates
 v2.transform = t.rotated(by: 45 * .pi/180)
 // rotates first, then translates
 v3.transform = t.concatenating(r)
```

[Green v2 is translated first and then rotated by 45 degrees, where as blue v3 is rotated first and then translated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWaEW.png)

Furthermore, the header doc information for `rotated` shows

```
Rotate t by angle radians and return the result:
         t =  [ cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0 ] * t
```

The multiplication should imply the rotation happens first, but the wording makes it seem that the rotation is second. Based on the results above, the wording correct (rotation is second).

The header doc for `translatedBy` also has wording for translation being second and the matrix multiplication showing the translation is first. But based on the results above, the matrix multiplication is correct (translation is first).

Am I making a mistake in this analysis? Or is there some inconsistency in the order of transformations based on concatenation and the descriptions in the documentation for these transformation and concatenating methods.

Comment: My book is quite clear that translating and then rotating gives a different result from rotating and then translating, and it illustrates both; operations are not commutative (order matters). And I show how concatenation works differently from applying one at a time. So what’s not clear?

Comment: And modern example code for all of it is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch01p017transform/ch14p371frame/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I understand order makes a difference in transformations (and matrix multiplication in general). By looking at both pairs of examples, it appears that there is an inconsistency in the order of the transformations. `s.concatenating(t)` is performed `s` first and then `t`, but `t.concatenating(r)` is performed `r` first and then `t`. According to the documentation for `concatenating`, it should be the case that `A.concatenating(B)` yields `A * B`. So the order should always be `A` followed by `B`. `t.concatenating(r)` violates that.

Comment: There is no inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have misinterpreted the first diagram:

[image]

You say:

> Green v2 translates 100 to the right and then is scaled by .1, where blue v3 is scaled by .1 and then translated 100 to the right

No. Your words are backwards from what the diagram actually shows.

Remember, a transform takes place around a view’s center. Ok, so why is the green view only a tiny bit to the right of its original center?

It’s because  first we scaled down to the center and then we moved 10 points right — 10 points because the meaning of a point has first been scaled down to 1/10 of a normal point.

But the blue view is a full 100 points right of its original center, because it translated that 100 points before scaling down.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have realized a mistake I made and I am becoming aware of another mathematical idea. My main mistake is as follows. There are apparently 2 ways of viewing the transformations, and the coordinate system is the thing to pay attention too.For example, the green v2 can be viewed as translating right by 100 and then scaling by .1 (with respect to the v2's original coordinate system). On there other hand, it can also be viewed as scaled by .1 and then translated in v2's new coordinate system. As for why, I am still trying to explore.

Comment: As for why, I think there might be a way to understand it by the following: The transform for v2 is equivalent to `t.concatenating(s)`. So the matrix is `ts` (not `st`). Using `x` as the initial point, we are considering `x' = x*t*s = s *((s^(-1)*t*s)`. The first way is as the docs describe, which is why the transform can be viewed as scale first and the translate. But the second way shows `s` first, followed by what must end up being `t` but in the new coordinates after s. That is pretty interesting. The difficult thing abut this is that the homogeneous coordinates mean we are working in R3

Comment: As for v3 in the rotation example, `v3.transform = t.concatenating(r)`. So the matrix is `tr`. One way to view is to translate by 100 to the right, and then rotate (but do so according to the original center). That is what I did not catch before. The other way is to view it as rotate first, then translate according to its new coordinate system. This also helps me make sense of the methods such as `rotated(by:)`.

Comment: I think I've explained why, however you choose to express it, the two sequences are behaving in completely parallel ways. I'd appreciate your accepting my answer; I went to a lot of trouble with this.

Comment: Your answer pushed me to the right direction. I think there remains some work on my part to understand how. I say that because according the [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) and [concatenating](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform/1455996-concatenating), `T1.concatenate(T2)` gets applies to point `[x y 1]` as `[x' y' 1] = [x y 1] * T1 * T2`, which means from an algebraic point of view that `T1` gets applied first, then `T2`. Your insight is a more intuitive geometric view that appears to be correct

Comment: Right, pedagogically I’m explaining it in terms of what you see happen, which anyone can reason about, not in terms of linear algebra which most people didn’t take or don’t remember.

Comment: @matt Expressing things in terms of the already-transformed space is somewhat confusing, and counter-intuitive to anyone who's used 2D or 3D graphic software— we're used to transforms that a relative to a parent in a object hierarchy (or worldspace if a root-level object) and transform ordering where scale doesn't affect the translation amount; rotation doesn't affect the translated position, and rotation doesn't skew the scale.  Internally, thinking in local space may be what's happening, but user-focused software tends to soften that into a “parent”/“world”-space conceptualization.

Comment: @matt So you're absolutely right about how Apple and OpenGL does this stuff, of course, but _“I’m explaining it in terms of what you see happen, which anyone can reason about, not in terms of linear algebra which most people didn’t take or don’t remember”_ is backwards.  You're actually explaining it in terms of the linear algebra math (necessary to know to be able to do this programming), **not** the TSR paradigms people are used to in Unity, Unreal, Blender, etc.  I'm sorry, distorting space with each T,S,R operation is not intuitive; having each relative to a parent's space is intuitive.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Ignoring the discussion in the comments (which is volatile), can you think of a way in which I might reword my _answer_ more correctly / helpfully? Perhaps I should add a sentence about "this is backwards from..." if I knew how to phrase it. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I don't know.  You answer made sense to me, but I've worked extensively with both 3D software and low-level 3D APIs (e.g. OpenGL).  To me, it's just one of the many equivalent-but-different ways of computing things in 3D (e.g. right-hand vs. left-hand, matrix pre- vs. post-multipliation, column-major vs. row-major matrices, Y-up vs. Z-up).  I'm not even used to thinking about S,R,T order— I'm used to a studio having a standard ordering (TRS, SRT, etc.) and just following the standard all the libs use, instead of thinking through the linear math possibilities of it every time.

Comment: @matt So the best suggestion I'd come up with is to suggest that in order to get the expected result (no skewing, or scaled translations), the programmer always use a certain order of operations with Apple's `CGAffineTransform`— translate 1st, then rotate 2nd, then scale 3rd (assuming you're transforming the space the next operation is working in)… but that's not really relevant to the question, and it sounds like your book covers this stuff pretty well.  Maybe the best improvement would just be to add a black crosshairs to the image in the centerpoint of the red box, with black text “origin”.

Comment: @matt Or at the very least, clarifying that most 3D software applies the TRS in that order so the end-result appears to be relative to the parent's coordinate space (since we have a human intuition to scale-rotate an object first, then position it in a space, and if a non-uniform-scale and rotation are in the wrong order, you get skewing).  So yeah, I don't really know how to improve the answer itself, since these are confusing concepts, there's competing methodologies in each engine, and I'm personally not innately familiar with Apple's approach (I've used `CGAffineTransform` rarely).  ;-/