# CGAffineTransform order of operations Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, cgrect

I would like to sum up multiple posts because nothing is really clear.

1. `myCgRect.applying( CGAffineTransform(A).scaledBy(B) )` does first B and then A ?
2. `CGAffineTransform(A).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(B))` does first B then A ?
3. `CGAffineTransform(A).scaledBy(...)` first scales(B) then A ?

   `CGAffineTransform(A).translatedBy(...)`first translates(B) then A ?

Is everything correct?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: CGAffineTransform doesn't have an `applying` method. Did you mean to include that?

Comment: I know you won't like this, but a lot depends on what you mean by "first" and "then". See my https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949576/341994 where I try to straighten this out; as you can see, even the evidence of the OP's own eyes has not been sufficient. Also see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927425/341994.

Comment: Plus I would suggest removing the UIAnimation tag and the UIKit tag. This is core graphics plain and simple. It isn't even really a Swift matter, if it comes to that, but let's leave that one.

Comment: @RobNapier Oops a typo, I though about the rect's .applying [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455875-applying)

Comment: @matt Let me expain what I mean by "first doing X  and then doing Y". We do something (X or Y) on an initial object. The initial object is transformed by the operation X, then this result is then transformed by the operation Y.  So first X then Y on "a" is represented with this parentheses : Y*(X*a)

Comment: But here : `let p = CGPoint(x: 5, y: 6)`
`p.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 2 y: -3).scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1))`prints `(7.0, -9.0)` which means that it first scaled (B) then translated (A). (which is not the order I supposed by writing A.scaledBy(B) !)